# error while delete rows based on cell.value excel 2013 vba (for loop)(overFlow)

Tags: vba, excel, loops

i am checking column P (starting from row 8)if it contains "Incomplete" then i want to remove the entire row , else do nothing , but it give me back run time error 6 OVERFLOW

This is my code :

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim i As Integer
Dim Pvalue As String

i = 8

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

lastRow = 0
lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

MSG1 = MsgBox("are you sure you want to remove the Incomplete rows?", vbYesNo, "Microsoft Excel")

If MSG1 = vbYes Then
    'clearing the body table

    For i = 8 To lastRow
        Pvalue = Range("P" & i).value
        If Pvalue = "Incomplete" Then
            Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A" & i & ":" + "P" & i).ClearContents
            Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A" & i & ":" + "P" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        Else

        End If
    Next
Else

End If

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True

End Sub
```

Comment: When deleting row use reverse loop, like this `For i = lastRow To 8 Step -1` , should do the trick

Comment: where are you deleting the rows ? you are just Clearing the Contents

Comment: Dear shai, thanks for your support, i tried the reverse loop now and same error is appearing

Comment: step into the code and tell us what line are you getting the errors

Comment: MSG1 = MsgBox("are you sure you want to remove the Incomplete rows?", vbYesNo, "Microsoft Excel")

If MSG1 = vbYes Then
'clearing the table from incomplete rows


    last = Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = last To 8 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, "P").Value) = "Incomplete" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

Else

Comment: it does not coloring any line thats why i am confusing

Comment: Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim Pvalue As String

 lastRow = 0
 lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
 i = 0
MSG1 = MsgBox("are you sure you want to remove the Incomplete rows?", vbYesNo, "Microsoft Excel")

If MSG1 = vbYes Then
    last = Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = last To 8 Step -1
        If (Cells(i, "P").Value) = "Incomplete" Then
            Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

Else
MsgBox "No Incomplete records found"
End If

End Sub

Answer (score -1):

thanks every body for supporting,
actually after reading about this error (run time error 6) one of its reasons that you are using a wrong data type for a variable,
i used 
dim i as long instead of 
dim i as integer
then it work fine.
thanks again everybody.